# resizing controller in UWP by user while running

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

how can I have a controller like TExtBlock in UWP that user can resize it by mouse?

I don't have any idea for sole this issue.
I tried flyout controller by XAMLBrewer but it just for manipulation not resizing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [GridSplitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/gridsplitter) control in [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit).

If your `TextBlock` is in Grid, you could use `GridSplitter` control to resize the TextBlock by mouse dragging.

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
```

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition  MinWidth="100"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="11"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txb" Grid.Column="0"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           Margin="12,12" PointerReleased="TextBlock_PointerReleased" PointerPressed="TextBlock_PointerPressed">
  This text to simulate the resizing feature of the Grid Splitter Control, try to move the splitter to see the effect RowDefinition MinHeight="100"
    </TextBlock>
    <controls:GridSplitter
        Width="11"
        Background="LightGray"
        GripperCursor="Default"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Grid.Column="1"
        ResizeDirection="Auto"
        ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment"
        CursorBehavior="ChangeOnSplitterHover"
        GripperForeground="White">
    </controls:GridSplitter>
    <controls:GridSplitter
        Height="11"
        Background="LightGray"
        GripperCursor="Default"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.Row="1"
        GripperForeground="White">
    </controls:GridSplitter>
</Grid>
```

It actually resizes the targeted columns or rows, not resizes the TextBlock. But the visual effect is the same with your description.

If you do not like this control, you would have to implement this function by yourself. There're no built-in APIs for you.

Comment: is it just for one side? how can I use it for horizontal and vertical?

Comment: Of course, you could use ti for horizontal and vertical. You just need to add a `GridSplitter` control in below row. See my updated code.